# How do I rewrite www.sitename.com/thing/thing.php?otherthing=something-like-this to www.sitename.com/something-like-this?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How do I rewrite

> www.sitename.com/thing/thing.php?otherthing=something-like-this

to

> www.sitename.com/something-like-this?

please help me with this as I can't seem to succeed. My host uses apache  2.2. Many thanks for your help!

**Update**

No I don't need that trailing ?  However, I used the Rewrite rule you offered me and it still ain't working. I also added a RewriteEngine On before the rules.

I have Linux hosting, .htaccess and the code is obviously semantically correct, cause otherwise I would get the all so popular 500 internal server error. I placed the .htaccess file in the folder thing and in the root of the site, but it still won't work.

Answer (score 0):

There should be an option to display it in directory format instead of the PHP `?` format. If not, you could use the .htaccess mod_rewrite rule to make that display in the `/folder/` way.

The way I do it is that I just upload my files and each page name is `index.html` and then I create folders, and put each `index.html` in the folder. Like this:

`/guidelines/`

In that folder is `index.html`, so instead of it being `/guidelines.html` it's `/guidelines/`

Looks better without `.html`

Comment: Be simpler -- just use mod_rewrite with single rule (unless your hosting company does not have mod_rewrite enabled .. which is very rare .. and usually on cheap hosting plans).

Comment: @LazyOne How do you get so much reputation? It seems very hard even just to get 1000.

Comment: That is not a lot -- this is a lot: http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet (the full list here: http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all)

Comment: @LazyOne Yes, but 4,000 is still a lot to me. I don't know how they get that much. :/ It's like impossible.

Comment: Well .. if you start answering on busy and highly competitive tags/categories (for example: php, java, c#) then single answer can bring you a lot of up votes. But if you do relatively quite category (like .htaccess, mod_rewrite) then average up vote will be around 1 (1/3 of my accepted answers have 0 votes .. and I very rarely see 3 or more). Try answering more, quicker and in more categories. On another hand -- what are you planning to do with all this reputation? MoneyExchange :P ?

Comment: Oh ok. As for what I'm doing with it, I don't know, I just want more reputation. Thanks for the tips. :)

Comment: Can't do that thing with index.html. I have mod rewrite enabled, just have no idea how to use it:D. And please ignore the question mark at the end of the re-write rule:
I want the URL to look like this:www.sitename.com/something-like-this
Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Al Fl I meant to make a folder for each page, and then put an index.html in each folder. The index.html will be the actual page when they go to yoursite.com/page/ That's how I set it up on: www.americaspoeticsoul.com When you go to a page, you'll see they are all folders instead of the .html at the end. (for example: `/contact/` used to be `/contact.html` but I renamed it to `index.html` in the /contact/ folder so the page would show up when you go to `/contact/`) But, you are doing it s different way with `?page=123` or something aren't you? Maybe someone else will be able to help with that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^otherthing=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^thing/thing.php$ /%1? [L]
```

No idea if you meant to have that trailing `?` at the end of the rewrite, I don't think that's possible. Note that the `?` at the end of the RewriteRule is to get rid of the query string, otherwise, the rewritten URL will still have the `?otherthing=something-like-this` at the end.